# What websites would I be allowed to DoS?

Tags: denial-of-service

I recently wrote an automated DoS script and was wondering 2 things:

1. Would I be allowed to use it on hackthissite.org?
2. Would I be able to make a Wix site and use it on that?

Comment: You need to create your own network for this, where you own and control all the actual hardware for the clients, servers, and networking equipment, and the traffic doesn’t cross the public Internet. Then what you have isn’t a DoS script, it’s a stress-testing script, and perfectly legal and indeed possibly useful.

Comment: You did good by asking this question here before attempting such activities. I wish you all the best while learning the trade.

Comment: You should only DoS your own enclosed experiment infrastructure.  Any ISP will bar any illegal DoS activities if their router/firewall discover it.

Comment: You're allowed to DoS http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1, and http://[::1].

Answer (score 8):

It might surprise you, but conducting an illegal activity is illegal.

To "hack" a website, you need the written authorization of the website owner and the website host (the owner of the material infrastructure).

When doing a DDoS (as mentioned in the first version of your question), you are abusing the common infrastructure known as "internet", thus you are not only harming your target, but its neighbors too. Just do not do it.

When doing a simpler DoS, you might still infringe on your contract with your internet provider. Of course, you still need the authorization from your target.

To directly address the two websites you mentioned:

1. The [terms and conditions](https://legal.hackthissite.org/terms) of hackthissite.org states "You must not use the Services in any way that causes, or may cause, damage to the Services or impairment of the availability or accessibility of the Services". So, you are expressly forbidden to DoS them.
2. You do not own Wix.com, event if you put your content on their website.

Comment: So just be sure because I’m nervous about being held liable, I would be able to dos my own wix site(one that is made without any subscription or other fancy things)

Comment: @Astra No, because you don't own that site. You are only legally allowed to attack things you own, or that you have explicit permission to attack.

Comment: Wix websites are hosted on computers that you do not own. Even if you own the content displayed on the website, you do not own the computers and the infrastructure (software and hardware) that makes your content available on internet. You do not have Wix's permission to hack them.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one answer to this question: you may only conduct security testing of any kind on sites that have given you express permission to do so. Period.

And no site is going to permit random people to potentially knock their site off the Internet.

So, before doing any testing, you need to contact the site you want to test *and ask them.*

Comment: So what would hack this site.org do? Do i need permission since the name of the site is inviting people to hack it ?

Comment: Have you read that site's Terms and Conditions?

Comment: "Hacking" and DDoS'ing are two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Check "acceptable use policy" / "terms and conditions", whenever it is not written at there directly, it will be restricted and also you need to check data center and ISP policy for both attack source & destination.